# How to print variable on picture in Python?

Tags: python

It's possible to print text this way

```
OUT = cv2.imread("Out.png")
cv2.putText(OUT,"Text",(10,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

But how can I get variable instead of text? This way it does not work

```
a=5
OUT = cv2.imread("Out.png")
cv2.putText(OUT,a,(10,30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

and I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: `a` is in int. Instead make it string type... `a="5"`, or `putText(..., str(a)...)`

Comment: Thanks, "str" is quite right